# ERROR TypeError: "_co.category.category_type is undefined"

Tags: angular, typescript

I a have two model one `CategoryTypes` and `Categories` each category type has multiple categories. These are my two Models.

`Categories` Model

```
import { Categories } from '../../categories/Mode/Categories'
export class CategoryType {
    _id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    slug: string;
    user_id: string;
    created_at: string;
    updated_at: string;
    status: string;
    categories: Categories[];
}
```

`CategoryType` Model

```
import { Categories } from '../../categories/Model/Categories'
export class CategoryType {
    _id: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    slug: string;
    user_id: string;
    created_at: string;
    updated_at: string;
    status: string;
    categories: Categories[];
}
```

And data is

```
{
    "_id": "5cb8c22ea7d8ec2c30849c3f",
    "title": "fdsffds",
    "description": "fdsfdsfdsf",
    "slug": "dsfdsfdsf",
    "categorytype_id": "5cb8c21da7d8ec2c30849c3e",
    "user_id": "fdsfdsfsdf",
    "status": false,
    "created_at": "2019-04-18T18:30:07.064Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-19T17:36:47.052Z",
    "__v": 0,
    "category_type": {
        "_id": "5cb8c21da7d8ec2c30849c3e",
        "title": "sgsdgdsg",
        "description": "dsgdsgds",
        "slug": "gdsgdsgds",
        "user_id": "gdsgdsg",
        "status": true,
        "created_at": "2019-04-18T18:29:49.544Z",
        "updated_at": "2019-04-18T18:29:49.544Z",
        "__v": 0,
        "categories": null,
        "id": "5cb8c21da7d8ec2c30849c3e"
    },
    "id": "5cb8c22ea7d8ec2c30849c3f"
},
```

And getting value with `{{category.category_type.title}}` it's giving right output with a error `ERROR TypeError: "_co.category.category_type is undefined"`. How can i fix this.

Comment: FYI: Angular and AngularJS are two different frameworks. You shouldn't be using both tags unless you're asking about a comparison between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JSON you posted , the interface definition should be as,

```
  export interface CategoryType {
        _id: string;
        title: string;
        description: string;
        slug: string;
        user_id: string;
        status: boolean;
        created_at: Date;
        updated_at: Date;
        __v: number;
        categories?: any;
        id: string;
    }

    export interface Category {
        _id: string;
        title: string;
        description: string;
        slug: string;
        categorytype_id: string;
        user_id: string;
        status: boolean;
        created_at: Date;
        updated_at: Date;
        __v: number;
        category_type: CategoryType;
        id: string;
    }

}
```

which is generated from [`JSON2TS`](http://json2ts.com/)

Comment: try using safe navigation operator. {{category?.category_type?.title}}